# general question amortized cost and worst case

Tags: algorithm-analysis, data-structures, amortized-analysis

lets say a data structure has operations called insert and delete both of which take O(log(n)) worst case. Suppose the amortized cost of insert is O(log(n)) and the amortized cost of delete is O(1).

Now if a sequence that has n delete operations performed on this data structure  that has n elements currently, then what is the worst case? If delete takes O(1) amortized cost does this mean the worst case (not amortized) is O(n) for n delete's ?

---

I think no because it doesn't seem right but I'm not sure how to explain it

Comment: Amortization usually refers to the entire sequence of operations on a data structure, not just some of them.

Comment: I think you are right. Amortized cost is measured over unspecified-long sequence of operations, but since you can't delete more than N elements from this sequence, average cost of each operation in this procedure should be O(1) and therefore entire procedure is O(N). In other words, if this procedure require more than O(N) time, how one can say that amortized deletion operation cost is O(1)?

Comment: sorry, I mean that answer to the question is yes, and therefore you are wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer hinges on the definition of *amortized cost*. Since you haven't given such a definition, let me assume that you are using the common definition.

Consider a data structure supporting operations $O_1,\ldots,O_m$. These operations have amortized cost $T_i$ (where $T_i$ could depend on parameters) if the total cost of a sequence of operations *run immediately after initializing the data structure* consisting of $c_i$ many operations of type $O_i$ is at most
$$ c_1 O_1 + \cdots + c_m O_m. $$
This bound only works if we consider *all* operations done on the data structure since initialization.

In your case, you are only considering one part of the operations performed on the data structure, and so amortized cost doesn't apply.

Comment: Yeah that would be the definition. So this wont be O(n) times for n delete operations because of the initialization cost ? Like my assumption of it being wrong was correct?

Comment: The answer is, we don’t know either way from the given data.

Comment: From https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2013sp/lectures/lec21-amortized/lec21.html I see that amortized cost is measured over n operations starting from arbitrary initial state

Comment: @Bulat This is meaningless. Taking $n=1$, we recover worst case complexity.

Comment: When n=1, any time is O(1). We can talk about some O(f(n)) only when we have some constraints for arbitrary n. Moreover, if we always start from empty structure, we can't say about amortized time of deletion per se. But googling for "amortized deletion time" brings a lot of results, including f.e http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~orzamir/pub/FindMin_OrZamir.pdf

Comment: The running time of a single insertion in a dynamically resizing hash table is unbounded. It could be as bad as $\Theta(m)$, where $m$ is the number of insert operations executed since the data structure was initialized.

Comment: And that's your conclusion? 1) we can't define amortized time for ANY sequence of operations that doesn't start from empty structure, or 2) we don't have one for SOME sequences ?

Comment: It’s perfectly possible to define everything. Several different definitions of amortized complexity might make sense in different situations.